# What is the name of this spirit manga?

Tags: kekkaishi

I remember reading a manga but I don't remember the name. There were two main characters a boy and girl, they are both protectors of a spirit ground which is located under the school that they go to. All of the monsters are attracted to the ground because they can evolve there, the boy and the girl have to go around and kill them by placing magical white cubes around the ghosts and other monsters and saying "Kai" which is the destruction spell. This is all I remember please help me find the name!

Answer (score 3):

It's [**Kekkaishi**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kekkaishi)

[image]

---

### [Synopsis](http://myanimelist.net/manga/105/Kekkaishi)

> By night, junior high student Yoshimori Sumimura is a "kekkaishi"--a demon-hunter who specializes in creating magical barriers around his prey. By day, Yoshimori's got some other demons to battle: an addiction to sweets and a seriously crotchety grandfather! Yoshimori's pretty 16-year-old neighbor and childhood friend, Tokine Yukimura, is also a kekkaishi, but their families are feuding over who is the true practitioner of the art.